# How to Submit Form Given Specific Json Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to Json, so please excuse the newb question.

I have a form in which I'm conducting an Ajax post to submit address information to a backend script for validation.

Here's the form:

```
<form name="Form" id="Forms" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe" class="uniForm">
<input name="Action" type="hidden" value="SHIPTOVALIDATE"/>
<input name="IsAjax" type="hidden" value="Yes"/>
<!-- <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="VerifyOrder"/>-->


<fieldset class="inlineLabels top">
<h2>Order Details</h2>
<div class="ctrlHolder first">
<label for="orderdesc">Order Description</label>
<input name="Order Desc" id="OrderDesc" type="text" class="textInput small" tabindex="1" value=""/>
</div>

<div class="ctrlHolder">
<label for="po">PO # <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <input name="Cust Po" id="PoJobNo" type="text" class="textInput small required" maxlength="20" tabindex="2" value="dgnfg"/>
    </div>
<!--    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="jobname">Job Name</label>
      <input name="Job Name" id="CustJobName" type="text" class="textInput small" maxlength="15" tabindex="3" value=""/>
    </div> -->
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="shipvia">Ship Via <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <select name="Ship Via" id="shipvia"  class="selectInput small required"  tabindex="4"/>
       <option value="" class="default">Select Ship Method</option>
        <option value="OT - Our Truck" class="del" selected>Our Truck</option>
<option value="WC - Will Call" class="pick">Will Call</option>

        </select>   
    </div>

    <div class="ctrlHolder" id="pickupdate">
    <label for="datepickup">Requested Pickup Date <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
    <input name="datepickup" id="datepickup" type="text" class="textInput small"  tabindex="5" value="11/09/2012">
    </div>

    <div class="ctrlHolder" id="shipdate">
    <label for="dateship">Requested Delivery Date <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
    <input name="dateship" id="dateship" type="text"  class="textInput small" value="" tabindex="6">
    </div>

    <div class="ctrlHolder" id="shipto">
     <label for="ShipTo">Ship To <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
    <select name="ShipTos" id="ShipTos" class="selectInput auto required" tabindex="7">
       <option value="">Select an Option</option>
       <option value="ShipToManual" class="manual">Manually Enter Address</option>
    <option value="0">A ACTION AIR*, 5241 YANCEYVILLE, COLUMBIA, SC 29214-0001</option>
<option value="1">A ACTION AIR*, 649 spring lane, sanford, NC 27330</option>
<option value="2">A ACTION AIR*, 1313 south briggs avenue, durham, NC 27703</option>
<option value="3">A ACTION AIR*, 112 cricket hill lane, cary, NC 27513</option>
<option value="4">A ACTION AIR*, 2911 duke homestead road, durham, NC 27705</option>
<option value="5">A ACTION AIR*, chickem poop, atlanta, GA 60609</option>

    </select>
    <br />
    </div>
</fieldset>

 <fieldset class="inlineLabels" id="shipinfo">
   <h2>Shipping Information</h2>
    <div class="ctrlHolder first">
      <label for="YourName">Your Name <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <input name="Your Name" id="Your_Name" type="text" class="textInput small required"  tabindex="8" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="CompanyName">Company Name <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <input name="Company Name" id="CompanyName" type="text" class="textInput small required"  tabindex="9" value="A ACTION AIR*"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="Address1">Address 1 <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <input name="Address_1" id="Address_1" type="text" maxlength="30"  class="textInput small required" tabindex="10" value="5241 YANCEYVILLE"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="Address2">Address 2</label>
      <input name="Address_2" id="Address_2" type="text" maxlength="30"  class="textInput small" tabindex="11" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="City">City <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
     <input name="City"  id="City" type="text" maxlength="25" class="textInput small required" tabindex="12" value="COLUMBIA"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="State">State <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
     <select name="State" id="State" class="selectInput small required" tabindex="13">
              <option value="">Select State</option>
              <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE">Delaware</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
<option value="GA">Georgia</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="IL">Illinois</option>
<option value="IN">Indiana</option>
<option value="IA">Iowa</option>
<option value="KS">Kansas</option>
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME">Maine</option>
<option value="MD">Maryland</option>
<option value="MA">Massachussetts</option>
<option value="MI">Michigan</option>
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO">Missouri</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="OH">Ohio</option>
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC" selected>South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="VT">Vermont</option>
<option value="VA">Virginia</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="ZipCode">Zip Code <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <input name="Zip"  id="Zip" type="text" maxlength="10" class="textInput small required zipcode"  tabindex="14" value=""/> 
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="Phone">Phone <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <input name="Phone Number"  id="Phone" type="text" class="textInput small required phone" alt="phone-us"  tabindex="15" value="(336)954-5009"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="Fax">Fax</label>
      <input name="FaxNumber"  id="Fax Number" type="text" class="textInput small fax" alt="phone-us"  tabindex="16" value=""/>
    </div>

    <div class="ctrlHolder">
      <label for="">E-mail <span class="redasterisk">*</span></label>
      <input name="Email" id="Email" type="text" class="textInput small required email"  tabindex="17" value=""/>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

<fieldset class="inlineLabels">
<h2>Order/Shipping Notes</h2>
<div class="ctrlHolder first">
      <label for="notes">Order Notes </label>
      <textarea name="OrderNotes" id="ta" cols="26" rows="7" tabindex="18"></textarea><br />
      <p class="formHint"><b>(Maximum characters: 175) &nbsp; <span id="charLeft"></span>  &nbsp; Characters left</b><br />
(Cross streets, special instructions, etc.)</p>
    <br />
    </div>


</fieldset>
<fieldset class="inlineLabels">
<h2>Continue To Next Step</h2>
<div class="buttonHolder">
<label for="freightmsg">**Applicable freight charges will be applied at the time of invoicing.**</label>
<input name="continuetocheckout" type="submit" class="button red smallrounded" value="Continue &gt;" alt="Continue to Next Step" tabindex="20"/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**AJAX Call**

Here's the AJAX call:

```
$(function() {
$("#Forms").submit(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'WebCatPageServer.exe',
  dataType : 'json',
  data: $("#Forms").serialize(),
  complete:function(data){
 alert(data);
}
});
    return false;
});
});
```

**JSON Response**
Here's the JSON response:

```
{"DidValidate":true,"Company Name":"A ACTION AIR*","AddrLine1":"5241 YANCEYVILLE","AddrLine2":"","City":"COLUMBIA","State":"SC","Zip":"","Modified":false,"AddressError":false,"ZipError":false}
```

Question:
How do I submit the form programatically if both AddressError and ZipError return with a false?

Comment: You mean you want the form to actually submit in the same way as if the user hit the "submit" button?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping for, yes. It makes sense that if these values are false (meaning the address validated) that the user shouldn't have to then hit the submit button a second time...just not sure how to do this...

Comment: The way I would probably do it would be to fire off another AJAX request to the submission page, then use a JavaScript redirect to take the user to whichever page they should land on after submitting.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I forgot to add, however, that the 2nd post needs to have a different action. The backend program knows where the user should end up based on that particular action...Is it possible to provide a code sample to give me a sense for how this would look?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It uses the fact that forms submitted via javascript's submit () dont undergo validation again.

```
$(function() {
  $("#Forms").submit(function() {
    document.Form.Action.value="SHIPTOVALIDATE";
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'WebCatPageServer.exe',
      dataType : 'json',
      data: $("#Forms").serialize(),
      complete:function(data){
        alert(data);
        if (validation succeeded) { // put here your rules for returned data valid.
          document.Form.Action.value="DOTHEREALACTION";
          document.Form.submit ();
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, there are posible glitches: The user could change the form data after pressing the submit button, but before the ajax is complete, so the real submit would send changed data.
For my opinion, the cleanest solution would be to implement the logic into the server, which then decides wether the submitted data are valid and thus can undergo further processing or not, and simply informs the client about the outcome.